# How to submit a remote modal form via ajax - jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a little different from the method of submitting a form via static form value in modal. Using the same method is not working because AJAX not submitting the form value from the shown modal. So,

**html**

```
<a href="remote_form.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xModal">load form</a>
```

**modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="xModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="xModalLabel">loading...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
//clear modal
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});

//submit form
$('#xModal').on('shown.bs.modal',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form=$(this).find('form').serialize();
    $('#save_btn').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'inc/data.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:form,
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**data.php**

```
<?
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**remote_form.html**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="xModalLabel">Reg Form</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" />
     </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" id="save_btn">SAVE</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, any comment is welcome!

Comment: when you click on save, what do you get ?

Comment: you don't have a question, you don't have a error,you just have a wall of code

Comment: why do you have 2 modals?

Answer (score 0):

Delegate your click event, move the event outside the `on('shown.bs.modal')` event

```
$(document).on('click', '#save_btn',function(){
   var form=$(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:'inc/data.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:form,
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Umm... according to my trials. Submitting a form inside remote bootstrap is not working. Unless you need to check if the modal is already loaded (shown).

Comment: I know how it works! But I tried with my solution and find no where on the net. Yes mine is working!

Answer (score -1):

You can set ids to input fields and then getting data from that id as follows.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
```

and on the script do like this.

```
//submit form
$('#xModal').on('shown.bs.modal',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#save_btn').on('click',function(){
    var fname = $("#fname");
        $.ajax({
            url:'inc/data.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
               fname = fname
            },
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: what kind of object is this:`{
               fname = fname
            }`?

Comment: it is that variable that i created to call fname id. you can see it before $.ajax call.

Comment: you mean `{ fname:fname }` with `:` not `=`